# BB 10 web works scrolling issue

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am currently developing an application in BB 10 web works. I am facing an issue of page showing a grey screen when scrolling up and down. This issue happens only when the content of the page is scrollable and the complete UI shifts up and down if we scroll. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the viewport for you app yet?

```
<head>
    <script>
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
    meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
   </script>
</head>
```